# Apache server fault after configure mod-security2

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security, apache-2.2

I configured mod-security, from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu . After that a restart apache service but i caught error:

```
The apache2 configtest failed. Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 97 of /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf:
ModSecurity: Found another rule with the same id
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

error log: (but I think thats not log from fault of mode-security)

```
[Sun Jan 11 01:40:20.278652 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5359] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I also use mode-evasive.

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? Did you read it and understand it? It shows a clear path to look for an error.

Comment: SecAction \
  "id:'900001', \
  phase:1, \
  t:none, \
  setvar:tx.critical_anomaly_score=5, \
  setvar:tx.error_anomaly_score=4, \
  setvar:tx.warning_anomaly_score=3, \
  setvar:tx.notice_anomaly_score=2, \
  nolog, \
  pass"


This is the rule from line 97, i read it, but i need help to fix it and start apache, do you understand me?

Comment: Can I change the ID? and what number can I use? I need real solve not only another error ;)

Comment: After I change ID: 900001 -> 911112, I caught another error on line 128 :D

Comment: Please use the edit button to add this information to your post (and use the text formatting tools). They are heard to read as comment.

Answer (score 1):

The Error is here:
Edit your httpd.conf/apache2.conf

```
<IfModule security2_module>
Include crs/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf
Include crs/activated_rules/*.conf
</IfModule>
```

Change it to

```
<IfModule security2_module>
# Include crs/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf
Include crs/activated_rules/*.conf
</IfModule>
```

With booth lines activated, 
apache includes 2 times the same config 
and then you get the Error with the same id while restarting.